# What is a speed drive?

Tags: plot-explanation, fast-and-furious-franchise, furious-7

In Furious 7, Ramsey asks her friend in Abu Dhabi what he did with the speed drive she sent him.

He tells her he sold it to a Jordanian prince, and she tells him that she had stashed "something important" inside of it.

Obviously, she didn't mention the God's Eye tracker she had created. So, her friend and the Jordanian prince knew nothing of God's Eye, but the Jordanian prince still wanted the speed drive for his car.

What is a speed drive?

Comment: Haven't seen the movie, but this souunds a lot like a hard disk with its own nitro injector to make it faster or some flash drive on drugs. Basically to me it sounds like some writer needed some technobabble term but couldn't be bothered to at least check Amazon or eBay to get some reasonable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your friend.

[The first result when Googling "speed drive in car".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjustable-speed_drive)

From the page:

> **Types of adjustable speed drives**
>
> Hydrodynamic drives or fluid couplings use oil to transmit torque between an impeller on the constant-speed input shaft and a rotor on the adjustable-speed output shaft. **The torque converter in the automatic transmission of a car is a hydrodynamic drive.**

It is never mentioned what type of speed drive we're talking about (the page shows you that many types exist). One of these types is used for an automatic transmission in a car.
Most modern cars built for racing (most notably supercars; which is what I would assume the prince drives) use "flappy paddle" shifting; which is a form of automatic transmission.